# Initialize std::vector by calling the non-default constructor of each element with varying arguments, without unnecessary copying

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

I am looking for the way to initialize  a vector with the minimal amount of copy.

```
struct T {
   std::vector<int> v;
   //some stuff here ; pod
   T(std::vector<int> vv):v(vv){}://a non default constructor
};
```

Now to initialize a vector, i do

```
std::vector<T> vec(n);
for (auto it = vec.begin() ;it != vec.end(),++it) 
{
  // do some stuff to *it;
}
```

the "do some stuff here" basically just redo what is done in the constructor, and so i have two initialization of T.v...
I also thought of doing

```
std::vector<T> vec;
for (int i = 0 ; i< n;++i) 
{
   std::vector<int> vv = // blabla
   T t(vv);
   vec.push_back(t);
}
```

which again result on vv being copied...

So how do i initialize a vector of struct, where each element is initialized using a non default constructor (call with different argument for each element) ?

Comment: That's not a POD.  A POD cannot have any user-defined constructors.

Comment: v.push_back(v)  ??  Please clean up the question.  Then, where is the data coming from for this constructor?

Comment: If you provide some details on how you concretely want to construct your `T` objects, we might be able to give more targeted advice. And indeed, your `T` is *not* POD. Also, C++11 makes lots of things easier by providing new ways to initialize objects.

Comment: You don't even pass the vector by reference. Initialization speed is probably the least of your performance problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `reserve` and construct elements in place:

```
std::vector<T> vec;
vec.reserve(n);     // now guaranteed O(1) insertions at the end

for (unsigned i = 0; i != n; ++i)
{
   vec.emplace_back(vv);  // or whatever
}
```

You can also use the old-style `push_back()`; with any luck, the compiler will optimize out several unneeded copies. You should probably also add an iterator-based and an initializer-list constructor to `T`, just to give you some flexibility.

Comment: You should probably also mention `std::move`